# Update your tax info - Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

As I have opened account, I got this kind of tax info related message on Google Play Console.

[image]

As per Indian tax standard its asking for GSTIN info as per my business.
But I don't have any registered business exist so I am not business tax payer of the country so I don't have this kind of GSTIN number.

So what is the solution in this case for me?

Comment: You should ask Google support about it

Comment: can you give me way to communicate with google play support?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now I got proper reply from Google Support Team and posting here so if other users have noticed same point then they can get relief.
Please read content of attached image so that you will get whole idea.

[image]

Comment: did they removed? i m still getting it

Comment: My side also same thing exist so no changes upto now.

Comment: Actually I gave it as registered individual instead of unregistered individual? is it something to do with it? Can i Change that?

Comment: No its default @sanjeev

Comment: Still, in my account, I have this kind of message exist but now I don't have any further way to do in this.

Comment: 30% Google Play transaction fees to the developer + 18% GST .... :( I'm programmer

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted google payment help desk. If you are an individual developer you can ignore this error let the banner flash. Google currently does not have category as individual tax payer and businesses.

This error will not affect your application uploads. This will also will not affect your payment receipts.